# How to Remove a Xamarin.Forms TableView and Re-Create It Without Application Crashing

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a `StackLayout` in `Xamarin.Forms 1.4.2`, and from code-behind I am trying to create a table view, and then just for a test I have a button to re-create the `TableView` in the `StackLayout`.

If I use the following, that uses a standard `TextCell`, then I can re-create the `TableView` as many times as I wish without the application crashing:-

This is on `Windows Phone` btw:-

```
TableView tableView1 = new TableView()
{
    Intent = TableIntent.Form,
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
};
myStackLayoutControl.Children.Add(tableView1);

tableView1 = new TableRoot()
{
    new TableSection("Section 1")
    {
        new TextCell()
        {
            Text = "Text1",
            Detail = "Text2"
        }
    }
};
```

However when I change the `TextCell` to a `ViewCell` such as:-

```
new ViewCell()
{
    View = new Label()
    {
        Text="hello",
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
    },
    Height = 100
}
```

It will display the `TableView` **correctly on the first execution**.

However clicking a button that clears down the `TableView` and executes the same code to re-create it will run the same code, however straight after it has finished the function **it will crash the entire application** with an **Application_UnhandledException** being caught!

The exception caught is:-

`MeasureOverride of element 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WinPhone.ViewToRendererConverter+WrapperControl' should not return PositiveInfinity or Nan as its DesiredSize.`

Does anyone have any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: When you Google the exception there are a couple of results which are similair to your problem. It seems to have something to do with the `HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand`. Could you try setting it to something other than `FillAndExpand` or `Fill`?

Comment: Yes this seemed to sort that particular issue.